# bootstrap placeholder not working on a input type

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a HTML which has a div with multiple inputs(with placeholder). For some reason the placeholder is not displayed properly.Also, need the 2 input button(text) to be placed next to each other.

Here is the jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/o2qt6910/

HTML

```
<div class="container">

      <div class="row row-bordered voffset4">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">Aisles</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">Poses</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">Exclusion Zones</label>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row row-bordered">
          <div class="col-md-4">
              <button type="button" class="btn" id="add-aisle">Add</button>
              <div id="aisle-coordinate-container">
                    <div class="col-md-1"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputKey" placeholder="X"> </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputValue" placeholder="Value"> </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8">
              <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
          </div>
      </div>

      <!--<div class="row">-->
         <!--<img src="/static/images/lena.png" alt="Italian Trulli">-->
      <!--</div>-->

  </div>
```

CSS

```
@import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css";

.row-bordered:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0 25px;
}

.voffset  { margin-top: 2px; }
.voffset1 { margin-top: 5px; }
.voffset2 { margin-top: 10px; }
.voffset3 { margin-top: 15px; }
.voffset4 { margin-top: 30px; }
.voffset5 { margin-top: 40px; }
.voffset6 { margin-top: 60px; }
.voffset7 { margin-top: 80px; }
.voffset8 { margin-top: 100px; }
.voffset9 { margin-top: 150px; }

.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: What browser/OS are you using? It looks like the placeholders are both rendering for me in Chrome/Mac.

Comment: its Ubuntu chrome...but even fiddle has a problemm, correct?

Comment: The fiddle has issues with the column widths. For some reason, they're not picking up the CSS for col-md-4 and col-md-8. But I do see the placeholders as "X" and "Value".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="row row-bordered">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <button type="button" class="btn col-xs-2" id="add-aisle">Add</button>
        </div>
        <div id="aisle-coordinate-container">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputKey" placeholder="X">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputValue" placeholder="Value">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is some issue in Fiddle in alignments. I've tested this in my browser, input elements are now in one line with placeholders visible properly.

Comment: I've updated the code. Please check that. I've tested and its working

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row row-bordered">
      <div class="col-md-4">
          <button type="button" class="btn" id="add-aisle">Add</button>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
          <div id="coordinate-container">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputKey" placeholder="X"> </div>   
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputValue" placeholder="Value"> </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
          <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Is this how you want it to be? I'm having a hard time visualising what is it that you want.
Do you want the add button and the inputs on the same line or next?

Edit: Changed the button to be on another row. There is no need for it to be on the same row, if you want it on another line.

Comment: Want the add button on a separate line , input type - text on the same line.

Comment: <div class="form-group row"> Use the form-group class and row class in the same div. That's why you are not getting desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Its not an issue with the code but more how you are using the bootstrap grid. Your parent container has `col-md-4` but the div with the input boxes have `col-md-1` which only 1/4th of the width to be shown so its squished down. If you remove the `col-md-1` classes it shows up correctly.

Quick suggestion: If you want to use a `col-md-x` class you can add `row` class to the `<div id="coordinate-container">`